# python escape explanation ( how break is triggered)

Tags: python-3.x, logic

Hello I am wondering if someone can explain to me why by clicking the escape key which Return 'True', the below code will 'trigger' the break hence escaping the programme. Is it because it returns a true 'value' to the def handle_keys()and this alone enough to trigger the if statement (if exit:) because there is no other conditions. ( Super beginner here, thank you )

```
def handle_keys():
    key=libtcod.console_wait_for_keypress(True)

    if key.vk == libtcod.KEY_ENTER and key.lalt:
        libtcod.console_set_fullscreen(not libtcod.console_is_fullscreen())

    elif key.vk == libtcod.KEY_ESCAPE:
        return True  #exit game

exit = handle_keys()
if exit:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend has confirmed that my logic is correct. Solved